# Rxjs Invoke service which return data in pages

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I need to invoke a web service for each of the item in the list ["A", "B", "C"]. The service will return data in pages (default page size 100). The first invocation of service(with page = 1 as parameter) will have total number of records set as a header in response and based on that I need to invoke the service multiple times. And I need to wait for response of all the invocations,  to proceed with further logic. Any pointers to implement the above using Rxjs will be of great help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254323/rxjs-observable-pagination is this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi. I got it working for my requirement, but the response is not in correct format. The response from each of the service call is an array of objects. So I think in the final stream should be having multiple array objects ( like [{},{}] []{},{} [{},{}]), But I am getting a stream of flattened objects. (like {}{}{})

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`expand`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-expand) operator you can recursively invoke your api (`getData(x)`) to retrieve paged data until you have filled your needs (simulated with a `.take(7)`)

```js
function getData(page) {
  return Rx.Observable.of({
    page: page,
    hasMoreData: page !== 4,
    data: [
      page * 10 + 1,
      page * 10 + 2,
      page * 10 + 3,
      page * 10 + 4,
      page * 10 + 5
    ]
  })
  .delay(1000)
  .do(() => console.log('retrieved data for page: ' + page));
}

getData(1)
  .expand(data => {
    if (data.hasMoreData) {
      return getData(data.page + 1);
    }
    return Rx.Observable.empty();
  })
  .mergeMap(dataObj => dataObj.data)
  .take(7)
  .subscribe(val => console.log('data: ' + val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.2/Rx.js"></script>
```