# RxJS: How to loop and handle multiple http call

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

Im using NestJS. I want to get all data from paginated API (i dont know the total page). Right now im using while loop to get all the data until the API returns `204 No Content`, this is my code so far:

```js
async getProduct() {
  let productFinal: ProductItem[] = [];
  let products: ProductItem[] = [];
  let offset = 1;
  let state = COLLECTING_STATE.InProgress;
  let retryCount = 1;
  
  do {
    const path = `product?limit=50&offset=${offset}`;

    products = await this.httpService
      .get(path, { headers, validateStatus: null })
      .pipe(
        concatMap((response) => {
          // if the statusCode is "204", the loop is complete
          if (response.status === 204) {
            state = COLLECTING_STATE.Finish;
          }

          // check if the response is error
          if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
            // log error
            Logger.error(
              `[ERROR] Error collecting product on offset: ${offset}. StatusCode: ${
                response.status
              }. Error: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}. Retrying... (${retryCount})`,
              undefined,
              'Collect Product'
            );

            // increment the retryCount
            retryCount++;

            // return throwError to trigger retry event
            return throwError(`[ERROR] Received status ${response.status} from HTTP call`);
          }

          // return the data if OK
          return of(response.data.item);
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          if (err?.code) {
            // log error
            Logger.error(
              `Connection error: ${err?.code}. Retrying... (${retryCount})`,
              undefined,
              'Collect Product'
            );

            // increment the retryCount
            retryCount++;
          }
          return throwError(err);
        }),
        // retry three times
        retry(3),
        // if still error, then stop the loop
        catchError((err) => {
          Logger.error(
            `[ERROR] End retrying. Error: ${err?.code ?? err}`,
            undefined,
            'Collect Product'
          );
          state = COLLECTING_STATE.Finish;
          return of(err);
        })
      )
      .toPromise();

    // set retryCount to 1 again
    retryCount = 1;

    // check if products is defined
    if (products?.length > 0) {
      // if so, push the product to final variable
      productFinal = union(products, productFinal);
    }

    // increment the offset
    offset++;

    // and loop while the state is not finish
  } while ((state as COLLECTING_STATE) !== COLLECTING_STATE.Finish);

  return productFinal;
}
```

The endpoint `product?limit=50&offset=${offset}` is from third-party service, it doesn't have one endpoint to grab all the data so this is the only way, it has a maximum `limit` of 50 per `offset`, and it didn't have a `nextPage` or `totalPage` information on the response so i have to make `offset` variable and increment it after the previous request is complete.

How do I replace the while loop with the RxJS operator? And can it be optimized to make more than one request at a time (maybe four or five), thus taking less time to get all data?

Comment: Why do you using pagination when you won't need it? Just grab all at once from the endpoint.

Comment: The pagination is from the API, it's not mine. The API didn't provide a single endpoint to grab all those data

Comment: Then give it a high limit value (like the max int value).

Comment: I think you didn't get my point, my code above is working, i ask if i can replace the while loop with rxjs operator. And i wonder if i could optimize it to make more than one request at a time

Comment: To make only one call instead of 100, 1k or 10k calls is the optimization. Your loop is wasting your resources - it doesn't matter if the loop running parallel.

Comment: That is the only way i can get the data. The endpoint i called is not mine, i cant do anything with it, its from a third-party endpoint and it can handle a lot of traffic, so let's ignore the resource problem if the resource you are referring to is from the endpoint side. Can you elaborate from my question please?

Comment: But you can post a very limit, like `product?limit=MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. If you want to optimize the code, then you are wrong here. Have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dennbagas guess this answer does what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35494766/3772379

Comment: @akop no i can't, maximum `limit` is 50 from the third-party endpoint, sorry i didnt tell it on the question

Comment: @OlesSavluk something like that, but the endpoint doesnt have the nextPage value, so i have to make a `offset` variable and increment it over the loop

Comment: @dennbagas that's correct. Use this example, but create local variable for `offset` and increase it with every successful request. Then proposed answer will work for you?

Comment: I think you need to use the `expand` operator here, along the lines of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58322826/7612287

Comment: @OlesSavluk can you show me where to create local offset variable and where to increment it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer from [RxJS Observable Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35494766/3772379), but increment `offset` every time request is made:

```js
const { of, timer, defer, EMPTY, from, concat } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { map, tap, mapTo, mergeMap, take } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

// simulate network request
function fetchPage({ limit, offset }) {
  // 204 resposne
  if (offset > 20) {
    return of({ status: 204, items: null });
  }

  // regular data response
  return timer(100).pipe(
    tap(() =>
      console.log(`-> fetched elements from ${offset} to ${offset+limit}`)
    ),
    mapTo({
      status: 200,
      items: Array.from({ length: limit }).map((_, i) => offset + i)
    })
  );
}

const limit = 10;
function getItems(offset = 0) {
  return defer(() => fetchPage({ limit, offset })).pipe(
    mergeMap(({ status, items }) => {
      if (status === 204) {
        return EMPTY;
      }
      const items$ = from(items);
      const next$ = getItems(offset + limit);
      return concat(items$, next$);
    })
  );
}

// process only first 100 items, without fetching all of the data
getItems()
  .pipe(take(100))
  .subscribe({
    next: console.log,
    error: console.error,
    complete: () => console.log("complete")
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.6.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Regarding possible optimization to make parallel requests - I don't think it will work well. Instead you could show data progressively, as soon as items are loading. Or change API as was suggested in the comments.