# Angular, Render 3000+ Reactive Forms without crassing

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angularjs, typescript

I'm facing an issue with a large array of products within an 'order' object in my frontend application. Typically, this array holds anywhere between 500 to 3000 products. Please don't ask why it's so large; I'm just working on the frontend.

On one of my component pages, I need to display a reactive form containing input fields and an 'Add Product' button. Clicking this button it dynamically add three new input fields for 'name', 'availability in warehouse', and 'requested quantity'. There's no limit to how many products can be added to a single order.

The problem arises when I navigate to the edit page. Here, I need to render all the products with their respective values. This means creating a form array with forms pre-filled with data from the order. I'm currently using workers to handle multitasking and logic like filtering.

However, when the form is rendered, the browser crashes. I suspect this is due to the DOM struggling to handle/render over 3000 x 3 = 9000 input fields, while also constantly checking for validation and performing other tasks.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this issue? I've tried using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, but it hasn't really addressed the problem.
[image]
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush did'nt work, need something that can render dynamicly on scroll while handling validation.

Comment: You're looking at [virtualization](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/dom-virtualisation/) where non visible dom elements are not rendered

Comment: what about validation on all those 9000 input fields?

Comment: One approach is to use the [RxJs `defer` operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/defer), which creates a new observable everytime the observer subscribes to it by calling a factory function. This could be used to create client-side pagination [as demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35494766/6519224).

Comment: @HitesH it shouldn't be such a big issue to validate the data, and keep the results in a lookup table somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Really, using [cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling) is ridiculous easy and you neen't paginate.

just installs "@angular/cdk" (it's not necesary install angular-material)

```
npm i @angular/cdk
```

And use some like:

```
   <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" >
      <div *cdkVirtualFor="let group of fullformArray.controls"
               class="example-item" [formGroup]="group">
         <input formControlName="id"/>
         <input formControlName="value"/>
     </div>
   </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

  fullformArray!:FormArray<FormGroup>

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((res:any[])=>{
      this.fullformArray=new FormArray(res.map(x=>new FormGroup({
        id:new FormControl(x.id),
        value:new FormControl(x.value)
     })))
    })
  }
```

I forked the before stackblitz and show the two approach in this [another stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rswqsu?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

**Using paginate**

Paginate in front-end a large amount of data, en example using ngb-bootstrap [paginator](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/overview)

As usual add a few variables and inject the service in our component

```
  previousPage=0; //<--necessary to know
  page=1          //page actual -ngb-paginator starts with "1!
  size=10         //number of elements we see at time
  data:any[]=[]   //our data
  length=0;       //total of elements

  formArray!:FormArray<FormGroup>  //our formArray

  constructor(private dataService:DataService){} //inject the service
```

In my case the service return an array of object `{id:number,value:number}`

So, in ngOnInit ask to the service to get the data

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((res:any[])=>{
      this.data=res
      this.length=res.length
      this.pageChange(1)
    })
  }
```

Our function pageChange -(that received the page we are going to show) it's a bit complex

```
  pageChange(page:number){
    
    if (this.formArray && this.formArray.touched)
    {
       //using slice change the elements of the array
      this.data.splice((this.previousPage-1)*this.size,
                        this.formArray.controls.length,
                        ...this.formArray.value.map((x:any)=>(
                              {
                                id:+x.id,
                                value:+x.value
                               })
                        )
      )
    }
    this.previousPage=page;

    //create a new Formarray
    this.formArray=new FormArray(this.data.slice((page-1)*this.size,
                                 page*this.size).map(x=>new FormGroup({
                                                      id:new FormControl(x.id),
                                                      value:new FormControl(x.value)
    })))
  }
```

To show the form array we use some like

```
<ngb-pagination
  [collectionSize]="length"
  [(page)]="page"
  [pageSize]="size"
  (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
  [maxSize]="5"
  [rotate]="true"
  aria-label="Default pagination"
/>
@if (formArray) { @for(group of formArray.controls;let i=$index;track i) {
<div [formGroup]="group">
  <input formControlName="id" />
  <input formControlName="value" />
</div>
} }
```

NOTE: See that we can iterate directly and use "group" because we are define our formArray like `FormArray<FormGroup>`

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-j57pcg?file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CDK scrolling.
It only renders X items, that are visual, there are some hooks. Like a fixed size per item works alot easier. Google on virtual scrolling or start here

https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling